# How to set the CategoryAttribute of a PropertyGrid to the SelectedItem of a list

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, propertygrid

I have a Windows Forms project in which I am trying to set the attributes of a PropertyGrid with properties of the item I selected from a ListBox. I have a ListBox called listBox1 with two values (called "temporary" and "temporary2") and a PropertyGrid called propertyGrid1.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SortListProperties
{
        public partial class MainForm : Form
        {   
                public class SortProperties
                {
                        public string Name;
                        [CategoryAttribute(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()), DescriptionAttribute("Description of item goes here")]
                        public string Info
                        {
                                get
                                {
                                        return Name;
                                }

                                set
                                {
                                        Name = value;
                                }
                        }
                }
                public MainForm()
                {
                        InitializeComponent();
                        var properties = new SortProperties();
                        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = properties;
                }
        }
}
```

Here is the initializing code:

```
    namespace SortListProperties
    {
        partial class MainForm
        {
                private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
                public System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
                private System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid propertyGrid1;

                protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
                {
                        if (disposing) {
                                if (components != null) {
                                        components.Dispose();
                                }
                        }
                        base.Dispose(disposing);
                }

                private void InitializeComponent()
                {
                        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
                        this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
                        this.propertyGrid1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid();
                        this.SuspendLayout();

                        this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
                        this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"temporary", "temporary2"});
                        this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 50);
                        this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
                        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(146, 238);
                        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 2;

                        this.propertyGrid1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(164, 24);
                        this.propertyGrid1.Name = "propertyGrid1";
                        this.propertyGrid1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(272, 261);
                        this.propertyGrid1.TabIndex = 3;

                        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(448, 337);
                        this.Controls.Add(this.propertyGrid1);
                        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
                        this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
                        this.Name = "MainForm";
                        this.Text = "Get Item Properties Test";
                        this.ResumeLayout(false);
                        this.PerformLayout();

                }
        }
}
```

When I run the program, I get this error:

> (15,23) : Error(CS0120): An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SortListProperties.MainForm.listBox1'

[This is what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSa60.png)

If someone could point out how to get the PropertyGrid to set the category name to the selected item of the list, that would be great. Thanks!